# Mapping a customized entity to a database column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I want to maintain a version number (e.g. 1.1, 1.3, 2.15, etc.) for my main entity. I can't use decimal to store the version as I have to store 1.1, that will get stored as 1.100 if I use decimal. Hence, I am planning to create a small version controller class which manipulate the version number and returns me major/minor/complete number as required, and want to map that with a varchar column in the database.

Example:

```
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}

    public string Name {get;set;}

    **// I want to map this property with the varchar column in the database**
    public Version Version {get;set;}
}

public class Version
{
    public string FullVersion {get;set;}

    public string Major {get;set;}

    public string Minor {get;set;}

    public void IncrementMinor()
    { // some logic }

    public void IncrementMajor()
    { // some logic }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FullVersion;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will not define `Version` as entity (i.e. declare db set on your context), then by default it will be stored as complex type. So, if you will store your `Item` entity, you will see following fields in database:

```
 Id
 Name
 Version_FullVersion
 Version_Major
 Version_Minor
```

All you need to do is marking major and minor properties as not mapped, and give pretty name for full version property:

```
public class Version
{
    [Column("Version")]
    public string FullVersion 
    {
        get { return String.Format("{0}.{1}", Major, Minor); }
        set
        {
            var parts = value.Split('.');
            Major = parts[0];
            Minor = parts[1];
        }
    }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Major { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Minor { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

This generates exactly three columns:

```
 Id
 Name
 Version
```

Btw consider to use integer type for major and minor version fields.

---

Another option - make your version property not mapped and add property to store string version value:

```
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Version Version { get; set; }

    [Column("Version")]
    public string VersionValue
    {
        get { return Version != null ? Version.ToString() : null; }
        set { Version = Version.Parse(value); }
    }
}
```

And add `Parse` method to your `Version` class (which will create version instance from version string).

Comment: Thanks for your response, It looks same as the way we can use enum in EF 4.3 Code First. Good idea, I can do that. But it would be great if we can directly map our customized object because many people will be using this entity. I have to restrict them not to use VersionValue property, use Version property always. I can't even make VersionValue property to private.

Comment: @Hitesh yes, exactly same approach as with enums. I've updated answer with another approach, which is think would fit your needs

Comment: Yes, that looks better solution. Thanks lazyberezovsky (sorry if I didn't call you with your name)

Comment: How do I ignore those properties (Major/Minor) through fluent API? I tried `modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().Ignore(e => e.Version.Minor)`, it didn't work.

Comment: @Hitesh Version is a complex type. You should configure it this way `modelBuilder.ComplexType<Version>().Ignore(v => v.Minor);`